# Transcoding AVCHD MTS to Motion JPEG on a Mac

Tags: transcoding, mac, avchd

*Bigtime video neophyte and I've not been able to figure this out after a day of trying.  Hopefully this isn't a big deal - pls assume I know nothing.*

---

I have some AVCHD MTS files from my camcorder which I want to convert into a Motion JPEG.  I know that's a strange format, but this is the recommended codec for a programing environment called Max/MSP (because it doesn't do temporal compression), which I'm trying to use.

(Btw the source video is really jumpy / unstable.  I made lots of quick movements when recording them.  I'm just throwing that out in there in case it has any affect on transcoding.)

So, I've tried using ffmpeg and VLC on my Mac and every time the result is super pixellated and/or the playback is really jittery.

I'm not sure if I need to change the container format, use a totally different codec, change the bitrate, or any of the other parameters in ffmpeg which frankly overwhelm me.

Maybe there's a simple solution - or maybe there's a resource that will explain to me everything I need to know (concisely, briefly) to figure it out on my own.

---

Here's the output from ffmpeg, btw.  It produces a file, but VLC on shows the first frame and Quicktime can't play it.

```
ffmpeg -i 00000.MTS test1.mjpeg

ffmpeg -i 00000.MTS test1.mjpeg
ffmpeg version 3.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.1.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '00000.MTS':
  Duration: 00:01:03.58, start: 0.800300, bitrate: 6745 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p, 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0x7f9890867a00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[mjpeg @ 0x7f9890810200] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, mjpeg, to 'test1.mjpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   20 fps=0.0 q=24.8 size=    1601kB time=00:00:00.66 bitrate=19652.8kbits/s speedframe=   45 fps= 44 q=24.8 size=    3138kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate=17122.3kbits/s speedframe=   70 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=    4697kB time=00:00:02.33 bitrate=16473.7kbits/s speedframe=   95 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=    6242kB time=00:00:03.16 bitrate=16131.8kbits/s speedframe=  116 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=    7782kB time=00:00:03.87 bitrate=16471.2kbits/s speedframe=  140 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=    9538kB time=00:00:04.67 bitrate=16726.4kbits/s speedframe=  163 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   11093kB time=00:00:05.43 bitrate=16708.8kbits/s speedframe=  183 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   12324kB time=00:00:06.10 bitrate=16534.5kbits/s speedframe=  208 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   13943kB time=00:00:06.94 bitrate=16457.4kbits/s speedframe=  233 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   15519kB time=00:00:07.77 bitrate=16352.3kbits/s speedframe=  257 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   17036kB time=00:00:08.57 bitrate=16275.0kbits/s speedframe=  274 fps= 37 q=24.8 size=   18046kB time=00:00:09.14 bitrate=16170.0kbits/s speedframe=  299 fps= 37 q=24.8 size=   19430kB time=00:00:09.97 bitrate=15954.1kbits/s speedframe=  325 fps= 38 q=24.8 size=   20687kB time=00:00:10.84 bitrate=15627.3kbits/s speedframe=  351 fps= 39 q=24.8 size=   21949kB time=00:00:11.71 bitrate=15352.4kbits/s speedframe=  377 fps= 39 q=24.8 size=   23232kB time=00:00:12.57 bitrate=15129.2kbits/s speedframe=  404 fps= 40 q=24.8 size=   24521kB time=00:00:13.48 bitrate=14901.9kbits/s speedframe=  429 fps= 41 q=24.8 size=   25786kB time=00:00:14.31 bitrate=14757.3kbits/s speedframe=  453 fps= 41 q=24.8 size=   26875kB time=00:00:15.11 bitrate=14565.8kbits/s speedframe=  478 fps= 41 q=24.8 size=   28025kB time=00:00:15.94 bitrate=14394.6kbits/s speedframe=  504 fps= 42 q=24.8 size=   29252kB time=00:00:16.81 bitrate=14249.8kbits/s speedframe=  529 fps= 42 q=24.8 size=   30373kB time=00:00:17.65 bitrate=14096.3kbits/s speedframe=  554 fps= 42 q=24.8 size=   31670kB time=00:00:18.48 bitrate=14035.1kbits/s speedframe=  579 fps= 42 q=24.8 size=   32862kB time=00:00:19.31 bitrate=13934.4kbits/s speedframe=  604 fps= 43 q=24.8 size=   34189kB time=00:00:20.15 bitrate=13897.2kbits/s speedframe=  630 fps= 43 q=24.8 size=   35514kB time=00:00:21.02 bitrate=13840.1kbits/s speedframe=  656 fps= 43 q=24.8 size=   36826kB time=00:00:21.88 bitrate=13782.4kbits/s speedframe=  682 fps= 43 q=24.8 size=   38169kB time=00:00:22.75 bitrate=13740.7kbits/s speedframe=  708 fps= 44 q=24.8 size=   39691kB time=00:00:23.62 bitrate=13763.8kbits/s speedframe=  734 fps= 44 q=24.8 size=   41156kB time=00:00:24.49 bitrate=13766.0kbits/s speedframe=  761 fps= 44 q=24.8 size=   42427kB time=00:00:25.39 bitrate=13687.9kbits/s speedframe=  787 fps= 44 q=24.8 size=   43759kB time=00:00:26.25 bitrate=13651.3kbits/s speedframe=  812 fps= 44 q=24.8 size=   45429kB time=00:00:27.09 bitrate=13736.0kbits/s speedframe=  837 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   47019kB time=00:00:27.92 bitrate=13792.0kbits/s speedframe=  861 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   48304kB time=00:00:28.72 bitrate=13773.8kbits/s speedframe=  885 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   49697kB time=00:00:29.52 bitrate=13786.7kbits/s speedframe=  911 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   51121kB time=00:00:30.39 bitrate=13777.1kbits/s speedframe=  936 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   52444kB time=00:00:31.23 bitrate=13756.1kbits/s speedframe=  962 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   53783kB time=00:00:32.09 bitrate=13726.1kbits/s speedframe=  987 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   55249kB time=00:00:32.93 bitrate=13743.2kbits/s speedframe= 1011 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   56504kB time=00:00:33.73 bitrate=13721.7kbits/s speedframe= 1036 fps= 45 q=24.8 size=   57766kB time=00:00:34.56 bitrate=13689.6kbits/s speedframe= 1062 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   59216kB time=00:00:35.43 bitrate=13689.7kbits/s speedframe= 1087 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   60757kB time=00:00:36.26 bitrate=13722.8kbits/s speedframe= 1112 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   62211kB time=00:00:37.10 bitrate=13735.4kbits/s speedframe= 1138 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   63693kB time=00:00:37.97 bitrate=13741.3kbits/s speedframe= 1164 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   64994kB time=00:00:38.83 bitrate=13708.6kbits/s speedframe= 1189 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   66360kB time=00:00:39.67 bitrate=13702.6kbits/s speedframe= 1215 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   67591kB time=00:00:40.54 bitrate=13658.1kbits/s speedframe= 1241 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   68794kB time=00:00:41.40 bitrate=13609.9kbits/s speedframe= 1268 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   70053kB time=00:00:42.30 bitrate=13563.8kbits/s speedframe= 1295 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   71602kB time=00:00:43.20 bitrate=13574.8kbits/s speedframe= 1322 fps= 46 q=24.8 size=   73001kB time=00:00:44.11 bitrate=13557.4kbits/s speedframe= 1349 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   74387kB time=00:00:45.01 bitrate=13538.3kbits/s speedframe= 1376 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   75815kB time=00:00:45.91 bitrate=13527.4kbits/s speedframe= 1402 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   77184kB time=00:00:46.78 bitrate=13516.3kbits/s speedframe= 1428 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   78430kB time=00:00:47.64 bitrate=13484.4kbits/s speedframe= 1454 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   79746kB time=00:00:48.51 bitrate=13465.4kbits/s speedframe= 1479 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   81117kB time=00:00:49.34 bitrate=13465.4kbits/s speedframe= 1505 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   82743kB time=00:00:50.21 bitrate=13498.1kbits/s speedframe= 1531 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   84374kB time=00:00:51.08 bitrate=13530.3kbits/s speedframe= 1553 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   85538kB time=00:00:51.81 bitrate=13522.7kbits/s speedframe= 1578 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   86826kB time=00:00:52.65 bitrate=13509.0kbits/s speedframe= 1603 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   88343kB time=00:00:53.48 bitrate=13530.5kbits/s speedframe= 1628 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   89845kB time=00:00:54.32 bitrate=13549.3kbits/s speedframe= 1653 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   91502kB time=00:00:55.15 bitrate=13590.4kbits/s speedframe= 1679 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   92702kB time=00:00:56.02 bitrate=13555.6kbits/s speedframe= 1696 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   93553kB time=00:00:56.58 bitrate=13542.9kbits/s speedframe= 1723 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   94751kB time=00:00:57.49 bitrate=13501.3kbits/s speedframe= 1750 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   95990kB time=00:00:58.39 bitrate=13466.9kbits/s speedframe= 1777 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   97272kB time=00:00:59.29 bitrate=13439.3kbits/s speedframe= 1805 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   98579kB time=00:01:00.22 bitrate=13408.7kbits/s speedframe= 1832 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=   99810kB time=00:01:01.12 bitrate=13376.0kbits/s speedframe= 1858 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=  101036kB time=00:01:01.99 bitrate=13350.8kbits/s speedframe= 1882 fps= 47 q=24.8 size=  102361kB time=00:01:02.79 bitrate=13353.4kbits/s speedframe= 1905 fps= 47 q=24.8 Lsize=  103872kB time=00:01:03.56 bitrate=13386.9kbits/s speed=1.58x    
video:103872kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

Comment: Show the full command that you ran and its full console readout

Comment: you could try compressor as I believe it has a Motion JPEG option

Comment: FFmpeg defaults to a bitrate of 200 kbps.  Add a -b:v 10000k in there